# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData() with no args

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to call API using Retrofit and Android architecture components but I'm getting this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData() with no args

this is the data class for the response

```
data class ForecastResult(val city: City, val list: List<Forecast>)
```

Services Interface

```
interface ServicesApis { // using dummy data
@GET("data/2.5/forecast/")
fun getForecast(@Query("APPID") APPID: String = "xxxxxxxx"
                , @Query("q") q: String = "94043", @Query("mode") mode: String = "json", @Query("units") units: String = "metric"
                , @Query("cnt") cnt: String = "7"): Call<LiveData<ForecastResult>>
}
```

and the api implementation

```
class WeatherRepoImpl : WeatherRepo {
override fun getDailyForecast(): LiveData<Resource<ForecastResult>> {
    val forecast: MutableLiveData<Resource<ForecastResult>> = MutableLiveData()
    RestAPI.getAPIsrevice().getForecast().enqueue(object : Callback<LiveData<ForecastResult>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LiveData<ForecastResult>>?, response: Response<LiveData<ForecastResult>>?) {
            when {
                response!!.isSuccessful -> {
                    forecast.postValue(Resource.success(response.body()?.value))
                }
                else -> {
                    val exception = AppException(responseBody = response.errorBody())
                    forecast.postValue(Resource.error(exception))
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LiveData<ForecastResult>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            val exception = AppException(t)
            forecast.postValue(Resource.error(exception))
        }

    })
    return forecast
}

  }
```

appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe that's not the issue, can you show us the retrofit API interface?

Comment: i have updated the post

Comment: `Call<LiveData<ForecastResult>>` do you have a proper converter for this?

Comment: Have you used the Repository?And do you also have a database?
Is there a sample of your project for me to see? plz

Answer (score 2):

Remove LiveData from API call and create `ViewModel` class have contained in `MutableLiveData` Object.

For Example:

API Call Definition something like this: ***(Remove LiveData)***

```
   @GET("data/2.5/forecast/")
fun getForecast(@Query("APPID") APPID: String = "xxxxxxxx"
                , @Query("q") q: String = "94043", @Query("mode") mode: String = "json", @Query("units") units: String = "metric"
                , @Query("cnt") cnt: String = "7"): Call<ForecastResult>
```

Create One ViewModel Class:

```
class YourViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var allObjLiveData = MutableLiveData<YOUROBJECT>()

    fun methodForAPICall(){

        mApiService?.getForecast(.....)?.enqueue(object : Callback<YOUROBJECT>
        {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<YOUROBJECT>, t: Throwable) {
                allObjLiveData.value = null
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<YOUROBJECT>, response: Response<YOUROBJECT>) {
                allObjLiveData.value=response.body() //Set your Object to live Data
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Now in your activity or fragment initialization ViewModel class.
And observe to live data.

```
    yourViewModelClassObj?.allObjLiveData?.observe(this, Observer {
       //whenever object change this method call every time.
      }
    })
```

So You can use livedata in ViewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so probably your API's response is not being correctly serialized.

Anyway, it doesn't make sense to wrap your `LiveData` to an API response. Just have your exposed object like so:

```
someLivedataObject: LiveData<YourApiResponseModel> 

// So whenever the APIs response comes in:
someLivedataObject.postValue(YourApiResponseModel)
```

If for some reason doesn't work use

```
someLivedataObject.setValue(YourApiResponseModel)
```

You can read more about the difference between these on the documentation, notice that I'm calling the `LiveData#setValue()` method, **do not** use Kotlin's deference setter method.

And since your view is observing changes to your exposed `someLivedataObject` the UI is updated.

---

This is similar to the RxJava counterpart where API responses with Observable wrapper don't really make sense, it's not a continuous stream of data, hence makes more sense to use `Single`.

---

Take these suggestions with a grain of salt, I'm not **fully aware** of your application's use cases and **there are exceptions to these rules**.

Comment: thank you, the problem was in resource class which created to wrap the response and exceptions

Comment: Thank You, Mahmoud Moustafa, I have same issue, and the reason was in the same place! ;)

Comment: @mahmoud moustafa awesome this could help you out, don't forget to upvote+accept the answer as per SO guidelines. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `LiveDataAdapter` to convert `Call` to `LiveData`, that way you don't need wrap your Retrofit response as `Call<LiveData<T>>`.
This adapter is similar to Rx adapter by Jake.

Get the `LiveDataAdapterFactory` and `LiveDataAdapter` from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapterFactory.java).

After adding the Adapter, you'll need to set it:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()
```

Self Promotion: I have made a video on the same over at: https://caster.io/lessons/android-architecture-components-livedata-with-retrofit